# form doesnt fires submit when i press enter

Tags: html

I have a little question... I dont know whats happening but submit event is working because when I click "ingresar" submit button, it sends all the data.
But when I press enter nothing happens.

I think the problem is that i have the form inside of a table....

Am I wrong? I think the problem is here because,as I said, when i press Ingresar submit button it sends the data.

Thx for your help! :)

```
<form id="forma-recurso" method="POST"> 
        <table >
          <tr>
            <td><p>Nombre recurso:</p></td>
            <td><input type="text"  class="campo nombre-recurso" maxlength="50"></td> 
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><p>Direcci&oacute;n:</p></td>
                <td><input type="text"  class="campo direccion-recurso" maxlength="50"></td>
            </tr>   
           <tr>
                <td><p>Descripci&oacute;n:</p></td>
               <td><input type="text"  class="campo descripcion-recurso" maxlength="100"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Tipo de punto de inter&eacute;s:</p></td>
                <td><select type="text" class="campo tipo-pto-interes">

            <?php

            $conexion=pg_connect("host= localhost port=5432 dbname=EmergenciesResponse user=postgres password=asdf");
            $registros=pg_query("select tipo_pto, tipo_pto_interes from tipos_ptos_interes where tipo_pto_interes BETWEEN 1 AND 4");
                while ($reg=pg_fetch_array($registros))
                {
                echo "<option value=\"$reg[tipo_pto_interes]\">$reg[tipo_pto]</option><br>";
                }

            pg_close($conexion);
        ?>                         



                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Latitud/longitud</p></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="latlng" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="salida-btn"><button  class="btn-salir">Salir</button></td>
                <td class="ingreso-boton"> <input type="submit" class="ingresar-recurso"value="Ingresar"></td>
            </tr>


    </table>

</form>
```

Comment: Your form has no ACTION tag to tell it where to submit to.

Comment: it doesnt have it because im using jquery. :)

Comment: Uh...  I see exactly NO JQuery there are all.  If you're asking why your submission isn't working, it might be helpful to provide the code that is doing the submission.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML code seems to be okay, so there must be something in your browser or in the PHP code: the "enter submit" doesn't work when the submit button is not present in the form, otherwise, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if it is working using inspector tool, press f12 to open it in your browser, change to networking tab, and try to click on submit button if something happens its ok.

I notice that in your form you are not using action form atribute, try it like this example: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: im not using action because im using jquery or i have to use it anyway?